# addEventListener not linking to element Id?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio

Trying to create a super simple script to say welcome to the page once a button is clicked.

The message hasn't popped up at all and i am confused as to why.

Code for button is in HTML

```
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>

<div class="container text-center">
       
        <a href="Conditions.aspx"  class="newButton btn" id="EnterButton">
           
        <span>Enter Irish Wrecks</span>
        </a>
         
    </div>
```

and then the javascript code is

```
var firstButton = document.getElementById("EnterButton");

firstButton.addEventListener("click", welcomeMessage(), false);

function WelcomeMessage() {
    alert("Welcome to Irish Ship Wrecks");
}
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: move the **script** at the end of html, or before closing body tag. Another way is to use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `welcomeMessage !== WelcomeMessage`. Also if you add parenthesis, you are executing the function instead of passing it as a reference. Omit those. `firstButton.addEventListener("click", WelcomeMessage, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that the WelcomeMessage is written correctly (as Javascript is case-sensitive) in the addEventListener call. Furthermore, you can't add paratheses, because you pass the function and don't want to call it in the addEventListener. I recommend you to use your browser's developer's console (F12 in Chrome and Firefox) to pin-point errors more quickly in the future.

```
var firstButton = document.getElementById("EnterButton");

firstButton.addEventListener("click", WelcomeMessage, false);

function WelcomeMessage() {
    alert("Welcome to Irish Ship Wrecks");
}
```

Good luck!

PS: Also make sure that you include your script file with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

**There are 3 issues in here**

- Don't call function in second parameter of `addEventListener`, just pass the reference/definition as its a `callback`. [Learn more on callback.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)
- case issue of the function call. function names are case sensitive.
- script execution is before DOM elements are initialized, so `firstButton` will have `undefined` value. Putting your script at the end would fix the issue.

```js
var firstButton = document.getElementById("EnterButton");

firstButton.addEventListener("click", WelcomeMessage, false);

function WelcomeMessage() {
  alert("Welcome to Irish Ship Wrecks");
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center">

  <a href="Conditions.aspx" class="newButton btn" id="EnterButton">

    <span>Enter Irish Wrecks</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Hope you understood the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you included your script before that button

So it cannot detect it

That's all:)

--edit--

Move the `script` tag to the end of the `body`